# VBA how to fix errors for strings starts with special character

Tags: vba, excel

I am fairly new in VBA, i am working on a project, there's small problem i am facing. I am taking newLastCmtTypeCol, newLastCmtCol, newLastNoteCol, oldLastCmtTypeCol, oldLastCmtCol, oldLastNoteCol as strings and i am only calling them in this part of code. so the error happend when one of the string start with a special character. I am taking input from sheet with alot of data. there's absolutely no way i can go through all of that data all the time. I just wanna ignore the strings start with starts with special character, so i wouldnt see any error.Here is the part of the code.

```
Dim newLastCmtTypeCol As String

Dim newLastCmtCol As String
Dim newLastNoteCol As String

Dim oldLastCmtTypeCol As String
Dim oldLastCmtCol As String
Dim oldLastNoteCol As String

newLastCmtTypeCol = "N"
newLastCmtCol = "O"
newLastNoteCol = "P"
oldLastCmtTypeCol = "Q"
oldLastCmtCol = "R"
oldLastNoteCol = "S"

For j = 0 To indexNew(i, 4)
    If (StrComp(ws1.Range(newLastCmtTypeCol & i + j), ws1.Range(oldLastCmtTypeCol & i + j)) = 0) And _
       (StrComp(ws1.Range(newLastCmtCol & i + j), ws1.Range(oldLastCmtCol & i + j)) = 0) And _
       (StrComp(ws1.Range(newLastNoteCol & i + j), ws1.Range(oldLastNoteCol & i + j)) = 0) And categoryCode = 1 Then

        categoryCode = 1
    ElseIf IsEmpty(ws1.Range(oldLastCmtTypeCol & i + j)) And IsEmpty(ws1.Range(oldLastCmtCol & i + j)) And IsEmpty(ws1.Range(oldLastNoteCol & i + j)) Then
        categoryCode = 3
        Exit For
    Else
        categoryCode = 2
    End If
Next j
```

Any solution?

Comment: Please post one specific example of strings leading to the error, and report the error you get.

Comment: i faced error when column O and column P was `#NAME, #NAME` . so after searching alot, i found this. when i removed the # and run the macro again it worked. So i can not go throuh all that data all the time. so i wanna just ignore the special character and run through it,

Comment: #NAME usually indicates a worksheet formula with incorrect inputs. You could append IfError() to that function to return a 0 or "", instead of #NAME. Or use some OnError statement in your code.

Comment: How do i do that for all 6 strings i am referening?

Comment: They're not strings, they're errors. The error you're getting is "Type Mismatch", because you're trying to read an `Error` value into a `String`, which is impossible. So yes, you need to check if a cell's value `IsError` before you can assign it to a `String` variable, or pass it to a `String` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Public Function DelInvalidCharacters(InputString As String) As String
    Dim ModString As String, InvalidChars As String, Char As String
    Dim i As Integer
    InvalidChars = "\/:*?""<>|';#,()%&$+- "
    ModString = vbNullString
    For i = 1 To Len(InputString)
        Char = Mid(InputString, i, 1)

        If InStr(1, InvalidChars, Char) = 0 Then
            ModString = ModString & Char
        End If
    Next i
    DelInvalidCharacters = ModString
End Function
```

Just call this function for each variable you want to strip bad characters out of

Calling it like this

```
Dim this As String
this = "*this"
this = DelInvalidCharacters(this)
```

Comment: Even if the function is useful, I am surprised this worked for the OP. The need was apparently not filtering special characters, but cells with errors.

Comment: Oh I just took the "when one of the string start with a special character" as literally him telling us what the issue was.

Answer (score 2):

Your issues seems to be with cells containing an error, not special characters.
If so, you probably want to filter out such cells.

You could use `IsError` to wrap your code, e.g.

```
    If (Not (IsError(ws1.Range(newLastCmtTypeCol & i + j))) and _
        Not (IsError(ws1.Range(oldLastCmtTypeCol & i + j))) and _
        ... _
        ) Then
```

Then you would be able to compare anything else.
You may want to use conversions between String and numbers, if needed.